# Incrementing .style.transformX on a click event

Tags: javascript, click, transform

I'm working on my javascript skills by building a slider...however I've become stuck on this issue.

On every click event I want to increment the px value on a translateX.

My best attempt had the slider working however it was just inserting the inline css on top of the previous click.

HTML

```
  <div class="slider">
   <button class="slider__button slider__button--left"></button>
   <div class="slider__viewport">
     <div class="slider__slide"></div>
     <div class="slider__slide"></div>
     <div class="slider__slide"></div>
  </div>
  <button class="slider__button slider__button--right"></button>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.slider-wrapper {
 height:500px;
}

.slider {
 position: relative;
 max-width: 1200px;
 width: 100%;
 height: 500px;
 background-color: red;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.slider__viewport {
 display: flex;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}

.slider__slide {
 flex-shrink: 0;
 max-width: 1200px;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background-color: yellow;
 border: 1px solid red;
 float: left;
 }

.slider__slide:nth-of-type(3) {
 background-color: purple;
}

.slider__slide:nth-of-type(2) {
 background-color: green;
 }
.slider__button {
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
z-index: 999;
}

 .slider__button--left {
 left: 5%;
 background-color: blue;
 }

.slider__button--right {
right: 5%;
background-color: red;
}
```

Here is the current code.

```
const sliderButtonRight = document.querySelector('.slider__button-- 
right');
const sliderViewport = document.querySelector('.slider__viewport');
const sliders = [...document.querySelectorAll('.slider__slide')];

const sliderWidth = sliders[0].getBoundingClientRect().width;

// The code in question //

sliderButtonRight.addEventListener('click', () => {
sliderViewport.style.transform = `translateX(-${sliderWidth}px)`;
});

// Comment End //
```

Built-in Javascript only please, no jQuery.

Thank You.

Comment: Could you post the relevant [mcve] HTML and CSS as well, please? This way it makes it easier for us to provide you with assistance directly relevant to your situation, and easier for others to understand, in future, alongside the example.

Comment: People won't need the CSS as all I'm doing is inserting an inline style created in JS. I've expanded the JS and added the HTML though as well.

Comment: When the user clicks the relevant `.slider__button` element how much do you want to increment/decrement the value by? As for the CSS, the code provided so far (as of writing this comment) gives this result: https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/bhnsnffk/, I can't help but think it should look 'prettier' so the user(s) can see the effects, and UI.

Comment: I just want it incremented/decremented by the `sliderWidth` variable value.

Comment: Okay I've added the CSS. I just wanted to keep the question on point as possible.

Comment: doesn't that works ? `sliderViewport.style.transform = 'translateX(-'+sliderWidth+'px)';` ? don't forget to increment or decrement it on *every click* so you can see it move.

Comment: To some extent I'm rather overworking your problem, to the extent that I don't have time to write it up as an answer, but this is my first attempt at a solution: https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/bhnsnffk/3/

Comment: Well it works cheers.  I don't fully understand it though. However I'll break it down tomorrow and gain a better understanding. Cheers!